# React-Firebase: Why is a console.log being infinitely called within one of my components?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

I'm creating a project in React, with a Firebase backend.

I need the details of an authenticated user passed from the `GigRegister` component to the `UniqueVenueListing` component, and am passing it via props.

In `UniqueVenueListing`, I'm making a `GET` request, then filtering through the data looking for a match. Strange thing is this - the console.log I have within the axios call is being called infinitely. Any ideas as to why? Is this some sort of error I've made with asynchronous functions?

This is `UniqueVenueListing` component where the infinite console.log is occuring:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { auth } from 'firebase/app'

const UniqueVenueListing = (props) => {

    const [gig, setGig] = useState({})
    const authUserId = props.userDetails.uid

    axios
    .get("https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings")
    .then(res => {
        console.log(authUserId)    // **this** is the problematic console.log
        const filteredGigs = res.data
        .filter(gig => {
            gig.user = authUserId
        })
        setGig({
            gig: filteredGigs
        })
        console.log(gig)
    })

    return(
        <div>
        
           {/* {
               gig.map(gigItem => {
                    return gigItem
               })
           } */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default UniqueVenueListing
```

and this is the `GigRegister` component that passes props to `UniqueVenueListing`:

```
import React from "react";
    import Header from "./Header";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import axios from "axios";
    import * as firebase from 'firebase'
    import { auth } from 'firebase/app'
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
    import UniqueVenueListing from './UniqueVenueListing'


    class GigRegister extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          name: "",
          venue: "",
          time: "",
          date: "",
          genre: "",
          tickets: "",
          price: "",
          userDetails:{}
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
      }

      handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
      }
    
      handleClick(){
        console.log('handle click reached')
        auth().signOut().then(() => {
          console.log('Successfully signed out')
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        this.authListener()
      }

      authListener(){
        auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
          if(user){
            console.log(`user signed in as ${user.email}`)
            this.setState({
              userDetails: user
            })
          } else {
            this.setState({
              userDetails: null
            })
            console.log('no user signed in')
          }
        })
      }
  

      handleSubmit(e) {
        let user = auth().currentUser.uid
        console.log(`this is the userid: ${user}`)
        const gigData = {
          name: this.state.name,
          venue: this.state.venue,
          time: this.state.time,
          date: this.state.date,
          genre: this.state.genre,
          tickets: this.state.tickets,
          price: this.state.price,
          user:user
        };
        
        
        auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(token) {
          axios("http://localhost:5000/gig-fort/us-central1/api/createGigListing", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "content-type": "application/json",
              "Authorization": "Bearer "+token,
            },
            data: gigData,
          })
      })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.props.history.push('/Homepage')
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      }
    
      returnUser(){
       
      }
    
      render() {

        return (
          <div className="gig-register">
            <Header />
            <h1 className="header-gigReg">Register a gig</h1>
            {
              this.state.userDetails ?
              <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Sign out </button>
              :
              null
            }
            {
              this.state.userDetails ?
              <h2>You are signed in as {this.state.userDetails.email}</h2>
              :
              null
            }
            
            <Link to="/Homepage" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <h2>Go to gig listings</h2>
            </Link>
            <UniqueVenueListing userDetails = {this.state.userDetails}/>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                placeholder="Event name"
                defaultValue="Event name"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Time"
                defaultValue="Time"
                type="time"
                label="Enter start time"
                id="time"
                name="time"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                inputProps={{
                  step: 300, // 5 min
                }}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                id="date"
                label="Select date"
                type="date"
                defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  this.setState({ date: e.target.value });
                }}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Genre"
                defaultValue="Genre"
                id="genre"
                name="genre"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Tickets"
                defaultValue="Tickets"
                id="tickets"
                name="tickets"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Price"
                defaultValue="Price"
                id="price"
                name="price"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default GigRegister
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Every time your function is being re-rendered, it calls that `axios` request too, hence infinite requesting, hence infinite console.logging.

Which should be the fix? This one:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios
.get("https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings")
.then(res => {
    console.log(authUserId)    // **this** is the problematic console.log
    const filteredGigs = res.data
    .filter(gig => {
        gig.user = authUserId
    })
    setGig({
        gig: filteredGigs
    })
    console.log(gig)
})
}, [])
```

That way, the `useEffect` hook acts as the `componentDidMount()` function in class-based components, it only gets called when the component first mounts.